# Qualidade Análise de Primeiras publicações

Tags: debate, filas-de-análise

Estou vendo que a qualidade das análises de primeiras publicações está caindo, ou está sendo usando somente para ganhar pontos (medalhas).

Coloco como exemplo o post:

[Não estou recebendo os dados enviados pelo usuario no email que deveria receber. Alguma dica como resolver?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131354/n%C3%A3o-estou-recebendo-os-dados-enviados-pelo-usuario-no-email-que-deveria-receber)

Ele foi feito por um usuário com 1 post e foi aprovado. Abaixo coloco o post original, que podemos ver algo vago e sem código fonte.

#### Transcrição da pergunta

Preciso de ajuda. Tenho um formulario de contacto a funcionar mas o nome, email e mensagem de quem envia nao chega ao email de quem recebe. Onde esta o erro no php? Desde ja o meu muito obrigado

código html

#### Dúvida

Será que temos como melhorar o sistema de Análise?

Comment: Faz tempo que existe uma robotização.

Comment: Eu particularmente sempre olho a análise das primeiras publicações e tento fazer o máximo para não deixar passar publicações ruins. Mas também tenho notado uma certa "corrida" de outros usuarios para fazer as análises, sem nem se dar ao luxo de avaliar a qualidade das mesmas. Na minha opinião deveriamos criar um sistema de análise dupla talvez, ou unica para o caso do usuário ter mais de 2k pontos por exemplo.

Comment: Talvez remover a gameficação da análise seja uma boa opção. Essas pessoas que estão em uma "corrida" pela análise, fazem isso pelo fato de existirem medalhas, rankings em relação a tal. Sinceramente acredito que a parte de análise deveria ser feita pela simples vontade de melhorar a comunidade.

Comment: @Rubico achei interessante este seu ponto, poderia ser visto isto pelos administradores